# Why is my select query returning no results?

Tags: magento-1.7

I’m doing a function that after the user saves the product it updates or inserts the product in a table, but to know if magento has to update or insert I have to verify if the product is in the table, when I do the select query I’m obtaining nothing in my variables

Here’s my code

```
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

            $tabla = $resource->getTableName('_destacados_web');

            $querySelect = "SELECT DCOD, DCATEGORIA FROM ".$tabla." WHERE DMARCA = '".$partesSku[0]."' AND DITEM = '".$partesSku[1]."'";

            $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($querySelect);

            $codigo = $results['DCOD'];
            $categoria= $results['DCATEGORIA '];
```

As you can see, the idea it’s really simple, just obtaining two rows of my table and saving that into the variables, but every time I run the code I get nothing in the variables,

I hope you guys can help me!
Thanks

Comment: you can just skip the verification and do an `INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE..`. Just make sure you set a unique key on the `DMARCA ` and `DITEM ` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could definitely use more information, but for start, `$readConnection->fetchAll($querySelect)` returns an array where each record is one row, so if you want the first record you could do something like:

`$codigo = $results[0]['DCOD'];
$categoria= $results[0]['DCATEGORIA '];`

Comment: Thanks!! that's why it was not working! thanks a lot!